# DLL Error when trying to launch Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Getting below error when trying to launch jupyter notebook. Any help to address this error is appreciated.

> _cffi_ext.c C:\Users\emathew004\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi__pycache___cffi_ext.c(213):
>   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/un.h': No such file
>   or directory Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\emathew004\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       from notebook.notebookapp import main   File "C:\Users\emathew004\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py",
>   line 47, in 
>       from zmq.eventloop import ioloop   File "C:\Users\emathew004\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq__init__.py",
>   line 47, in 
>       from zmq import backend   File "C:\Users\emathew004\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py",
>   line 40, in 
>       reraise(*exc_info)   File "C:\Users\emathew004\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py",
>   line 34, in reraise
>       raise value   File "C:\Users\emathew004\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       _ns = select_backend(first)   File "C:\Users\emathew004\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py",
>   line 28, in select_backend
>       mod = **import**(name, fromlist=public_api)   File "C:\Users\emathew004\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython__init__.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       from . import (constants, error, message, context, ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this problem,  which I solved as follows.

1. `conda uninstall pyzmq` (uninstall pyzmq)
2. `conda install pyzmq` (reinstall pyzmq)
3. `conda install jupyter` (reinstall jupyter)

Answer (score 0):

You need a corresponding version of visual c++ redistribution.